# How to replicate rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a pandas `DataFrame`:

```
    A
0  11
1  22
```

I I would like to replicate each row while inserting a new column `B` with running values in order to get the resulting `DataFrame`:

```
    A  B
0  11  0
1  11  1
2  11  2
3  22  0
4  22  1
5  22  3
```

I managed to do this by the following loop:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[11],
                  [22],
                  ], columns=['A'])
n = 3
a['B'] = 1
res = a.copy()
for i in range(n-1):
  a['B'] = i+2
  res = res.append(a,ignore_index=1)
res = res.sort(['A','B'],axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But I wonder if there isn't a cleaner and more efficient method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([11, 22], columns=['A'])

Out[61]: 
    A
0  11
1  22

def replicate_func(group, n=3):
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.repeat(group.A.values, n), B=np.arange(n)))

df.groupby(level=0).apply(replicate_func).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[62]: 
    A  B
0  11  0
1  11  1
2  11  2
3  22  0
4  22  1
5  22  2
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't realize that if `groupby.apply` returns a `DataFrame`, it is added as another level in the `MultiIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this approach:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([11, 22], columns=['A'])

pd.DataFrame({'A':[x for x in df.A.tolist() for i in range(n)],'B':range(n)*len(df)})

Out[29]:
    A  B
0  11  0
1  11  1
2  11  2
3  22  0
4  22  1
5  22  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Though it gives the wrong answer. But a combination of your answer and Jianxun's answer is probably the easiest: `pd.DataFrame({'A':np.repeat(df.A.values, n),'B':range(n)*len(df)})`

Comment: There was some typo! I edited the solution , which is still base Python (apart from Pandas)